# Math.ceil(x / 50d) - What is the "50d"

Tags: java, math, ceil

I jsut found this code snippet and was wondering what the `50d` actually means? I've been searching the web, but can't find anything useful.

Here' the complete code snippet:

```
public int CalculateMinimumDiameterFilter(){
    CalculateFilterAreaRequirement();
    double val1 = filterAreaRequirement /Math.PI;
    double val2 = Math.sqrt(val1);
    double val3 = val2 * 2;

    int val4 = (int)Math.round(val3 * 1000);
    minimumDiameterFilter = (int) (Math.ceil(val4 / 50d) * 50);

    return minimumDiameterFilter;
}
```

Can anyone explain to me what the `50d` actually does?

Comment: `50d` is 50 as a double

Comment: it defines the 50 as a double. 50f would be float.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: Overall, it's not very common to use `d` to mark a number as double. You can also just write `50.0` and everybody knows what you mean. Remember, however, that you need to write `50.0f` if you actually want a float, not a double. That's why everybody is more used to seeing `f`, but not `d`. :)

Comment: `50d == 50.0` the `d` is for `double`

Comment: People are downvoting you because they assume you didnt do prior research. On the other hand, especially for newbies, it can be hard to do the prior research - if you dont know about literals; and their syntax ... how are you supposed to find information about them. Long story short: +1 from me ...

Answer (score 3):

It is an explicit declaration of a number to be a `double` as defined in the JLS

[3.10.2. Floating-Point Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2)

> A floating-point literal is of type float if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter F or f; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter D or d

Answer (score 2):

## You may take a look at [Java Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) which will give you a good explanation.

`50d` in this case means the 50 is not of type integer (`int`) by of type double (50.0).

Not only we can do `50d`. You may also see people writing things like:

```
long serialNo = 1234567L;
```

In this case the `L` after the number means that I want to let serialNo be of type `long`. If you don't place the `L`, the default type of whole number will be integer (`int`).

---

Instead of writing `50d`, the person who writes that code could have written it as **50.0** as well. It will mean the same thing in this case because by default, floating point values in Java are `double`. Whole numbers are `int` unless otherwise specified by the postfix (such as `l`, `d`, `f`..etc).

## Example:

```
double d1 = 50.0;      //ok! 50.0 will be double by default
double d2 = 50.0d;     //ok! 50.0 is already in double, no harm putting a "d"
double d3 = 50d;       //ok! 50 becomes a double
double d4 = 50;        //ok! trying to store int into double (no loss of precision)
double d5 = 50f;       //ok! trying to store float into double (no loss of precision)

float f1 = 0.1f;  //ok!
float f2 = 0.0;   //not ok! trying to store double into float (loss of precision)
float f3 = 50d;   //not ok! trying to store double into float (loss of precision)
```

Answer (score 1):

`50d` means **the number 50 with `double` type**.
This is required because `val4` as an `int`, divided by `50` as an `int`, will return an `int` and Java will be rounding it to the *floor*, which is not what is expected.

Answer (score 1):

`d` is short for `double`. Standard the number `50` without any decimal (ie: `50.0`) is just an `int`. You need to add the `d` to plain `50` to state that you want it expressed as a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

The `d` suffix forces it to be a `double` literal instead of an `int` literal.